# Can I hide the element if it doesn't fit the available width using css only?

Tags: html, css

I have a header and an image that should be horizontally laid out on the absolutely positioned div. I'm showing the text in the subdiv with the fixed width. I'm trying to hide the image if it doesn't fit into the absolutely positioned container by the means of CSS3, but I can't. I know it's possible to do with JS, but maybe there is a CSS3 way?

```css
.container {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 60px;
  right: 60px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 400px;
}

.part-one {
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 22pt;
  color: white;
  min-width: 300px;
}

.part-two {
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  min-width: 50%;
}

.header {
  font-size: 50pt;
  color: blue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: relative; width: 500px; height:500px;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="part-one">
      <h1 class="header">This is some header</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="utilizationContainer" class="part-two">
      <img src="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8r72g/5/

It's ok if it works only in IE10.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've found how this can be done. If I use `display:block` on the `.container` and `float:left` in the inner containers, the image will be wrapped if it doesn't fit the width. And if I use `overflow: hidden`, the image will be moved under the text and hidden.

Here is the fiddle that proves this trick works: http://jsfiddle.net/8r72g/8/

Comment: Hmm.. it works for me on Win8 + FF23/Chrome29/IE10. Do you see a part of the image or what's the problem?

Comment: im using win7. not seeing any image, only the text.

Comment: A few moments later... I was looking for this effect as well and I found this answer. Even though your fiddle doesn't work for me, the technique does. Check my own example here: https://jsfiddle.net/q4m2grnz/ Tested on chrome/Firefox on windows.

Comment: FYI Amazon uses this technique on their main page for the links under the search bar

Comment: Flexbox users can do a similar effect by making use of a fixed height, flex-flow: wrap, overflow: hidden, and (depending on your scenario) gap

Answer (score 4):

If you'd like to [hide overflowing elements and expand remaining elements to fit snugly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45622861/display-only-the-number-of-items-that-will-fit-and-then-expand-to-fit-snugly), you can expand [Shalom Aleichem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18796542/937377) to do the trick:

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul > li  {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: block;
  flex: 1 0 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
</ul>
```

[More details available at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45622862/937377), and [another approach using CSS grid is explained at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45623350/937377).

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two methods you might use to solve this. The first would be to set a max-width for any images of the container, this doesnt hide the image however:

```
.container img{max-width:100%;}
```

the second option would be to use responsive design based on screen size. Similar to what Thanos mentioned, but within the same stylesheet. However your question doesn't mention a change in the window size, simply a change in image size, so this is probably not what you want...

```
@media screen and (max-width:500px){    
    .container img{display:none;}
}
```

A third option would be to use javascript, as you mentioned... I think this would be the easiest method.

take a look at - http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/conditionally-resize-image-based-on-width/

Comment: Disagree. I think the media query you mentioned is the easiest. But still a good answer.

Comment: The first way doesn't hide the image, the third is known, but I'm looking for css way to do this. The second variant is pretty much the same that Thanos advised, but it doesn't work for me, please read my comment to his post.

Answer (score 0):

What you will need to do is basically call a css file when the screen size is too small or too large in order to hide/show things that won't fit into the screen.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 900px)' href='css/medium.css' />
```

Comment: It might work if the parent div was of the screen size, but it's smaller. I mean, suppose that my screen is bigger than the absolutely positioned container. And this container is in its left half. When I resize it the css of the image should not change.