# Display only the number of items that will fit, and then expand to fit snugly

Tags: css, layout

I have a container that I want to fit a number of children in horizontally, but I know I have more children than will often fit.

```
+-----------------------+
|                       |
|                       |
+-----------------------+

+----+ +----+ +----+ +----+ +----+ +----+ 
|    | |    | |    | |    | |    | |    | 
|    | |    | |    | |    | |    | |    | 
+----+ +----+ +----+ +----+ +----+ +----+
```

Using only CSS, how do I only display the items that can fit, and expand them to fit snugly?

Desired result:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |     |
|     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@NathanArthur's solution is great for cases where you have a fixed height, however in the case you don't know your height things get a bit more hairy.

To do this without a fixed height you can use `display: grid`. Browser **[support for css grid](http://caniuse.com/css-grid/)** currently is pretty limited to latest versions, but I believe this would be one of few (if not the only) way to do with without a fixed height.

But what you can do is set up a `display: grid` with `auto-fit` columns using the `repeat()` function combined with the `minmax()` function. This will give you columns with a minimum size set by you, which will fill the rest of the space needed. Combine this with `grid-auto-rows: 0px` which will hide any additional rows added by child auto placement which happens if they start to go outside the bounds of the defined `grid-template` parameters. Looks a little something like this, note no defined heights and variable widths:

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 350px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-auto-columns: 0px;
  grid-auto-rows: 0px;
}

ul.test2{
  width: 520px;
}

ul > li  {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2<br><br><br> with some extra height</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
</ul>
<ul class="test2">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2<br><br><br> with some extra height</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is really awesome! Can't wait for support. :)

Comment: Looks like firefox and chrome support is pretty good, and IE has some sort of support, thought I don't think that includes some of the functions used to achieve this. http://caniuse.com/css-grid

Comment: What happens in a browser that doesn't support grid? It might be acceptable if it degrades semi-gracefully. You might even be able to combine the two techniques, if you check for grid support in the stylesheet.

Comment: comparing support of `grid` to `flex` I'd say it's not worth using `flex` as a fallback for `grid` I'd go with some other solution using fixed widths (no expand to fit) and something like `li:nth-child(n+3){ display: none }` or something  as a fallback. Could be annoying to implement that way though... http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: What do you do when you want grid columns to be sized based on the contents of the cell? Repeat function forces us to make all cells equal width

Answer (score 6):

The solution can be broken into two pieces:

## Hiding elements that don't fit

- Give the container a defined width and height.
- Define children's height to be the same as the container's height.
- Set the container to `overflow: hidden;` so children that wrap disappear.

(Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18796542/937377) for inspiring this part of the solution.)

## Expanding children that do fit to take up available space snugly

- Set your container as `display: flex;` so children can grow.
- Set your container to `flex-wrap: wrap;` so children that won't fit can still wrap and disappear.
- Set children to `flex: 1 0 [desired minimum width];` so children can only grow, not shrink.

## The result

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul > li  {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: block;
  flex: 1 0 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Fixed height is unfortunate, but I can't think of another way it can be done otherwise without JS...

Comment: @Don Agreed. I haven't tested, but I think this is probably compatible with percentage heights, though.

Comment: I figured it out, using `display: grid`. So not so great browser support, but it works! :D