Is there a way to prevent thumbnails from being cut off when parent container resizes
I created an image viewer with thumbnails which can be scrolled horizontally. The images are loaded dynamically for a selected feature and vary in number. The image viewer resizes to fit the screen size and I want the thumbnail parent container to resize as well to hold more thumbnails on larger screen sizes and vice versa. I was hoping there was a way to prevent thumbnails from being visible in the parent scroll element unless there was enough room so the entire thumbnail would come into view. Right now the parent thumbnail container is set to a fixed width, but ideally the container would expand with the size of the viewer. Here is the css for the thumbnail container and scroll buttons.
.thumbnail {
      width: 110px;
      overflow: visible;
      height: 80px;
      flex-direction: row;
      display: inline-flex;
      list-style-type: none;
      padding-right: 6px;
      padding-top: 6px;
      float: none;
    }

.image-thumb {
      height: 90%;
      max-width: 100px;
      border-radius: 4px;
      object-fit: cover;
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      -webkit-transition-property: all;
      -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
      -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
    }

#thumbnail-container {
      display: flex;
      height: 80px;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }

    #thumbnailListDiv {
      text-align: center;
      height: 80px;
      margin: auto;
      width: 660px;
      overflow: hidden;
      white-space: nowrap;
      padding-inline-start: 10px;
      scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    }

    .thumb-scroll-prev, .thumb-scroll-next {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
      width: 30px;
      color: #fff;
      opacity: .5;
    }

    .thumb-scroll-prev {
      margin-left: 5px;
    }

    .thumb-scroll-next {
      margin-right: 5px;
    }

Fixed width

Expands to fit space (preferred)

It would be great of the last thumbnail would remain hidden until there was enough room for it to fit entirely.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18776322/can-i-hide-the-element-if-it-doesnt-fit-the-available-width-using-css-only
